# ¿Cómo puedo obtener y mostrar los datos que se guardan en la variable "data"?

Tags: javascript, html5

```
window.onload = function() {
    webgazer.setRegression('ridge') /*currently must set regression and tracker */
        .setTracker('clmtrackr')
        .setGazeListener(function(data, clock) {
            console.log(data); /* Datais an object containig an x and y key which are the prediction coordinates (no bounds limiting) */
            console.log(clock); /* Elapsed time in milliseconds since webgazer.begin() was called */
        })
        .begin()
        .showPredictionPoints(true); /* Shows a square every 100 milliseconds since webgazer.begin() was called */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Cuando la function anonimo en .SetGazeListen() es llamada, "data" va a tener un valor.  No tiene que obtener nada, el valor es dado a Ud.

Puede mostrarlo como cualquier cosa...por ejemplo:

```
alert(data);
```

dependiende en cual tipo de object data contiene.

Comment: Hola Duston, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Disculpa pero soy nuevo en esto del javascript, ¿entonce cómo quedaría el código agregando lo que me dijiste?

Comment: Bueno, puede cambiar {console.log(data)} a {alert(data)} para probar.  La funcion está llamda cuando la cosa¨{Gaze} ocurre, Ud. Llama .begin(), y entonces pasa algun tiempo.  Cuando el data está listo (despues del llamo al .begin()), el sistemo llama el "callback" creado en .setGazeListener().  Espero que ayude...

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus sugerencias Duston, con lo que me dijiste pude hacerlo.